# Size of a union of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

We were ask to prove that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|‫‪$.
It was easy to prove it using a Venn diagram, but I think we might
be expected to do if more formally. Is there a formal way?

Comment: What does $|A|$ mean?  Is $|\cdot|$ a measure?  Or maybe the sets are finite?

Comment: just observe that if you do $|A|+|B|$ you count twice the elements in $A\cap B$.

Comment: Suppose that you want to give a dollar to everyone in $A\cup B$. If you give a dollar to everyone in $A$, and then give a dollar to everyone in $B, \dots$.

Comment: I am fairly certain that this question appeared here perhaps infinitely many times before. I cannot find it though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$A\cup B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A) \cup (A\cap B)$. These three sets are disjoint, so
$$
|A\cup B| = |A\setminus B| + |B\setminus A| + |(A\cap B)| 
$$
But $A\setminus B = A\setminus(A\cap B)$, so $|A\setminus B|=|A|-|A\cap B|$. A similar equality holds for $|B \setminus A|$. Substitution of these into the displayed equation above yields your result.

Of course, one might need to formally show that  $|A\setminus (A\cap B)| = |A|-|A\cap B|$. I can't decide if this is any less obvious than the original proposition...

Comment: I have seen $A \setminus B$, $A \smallsetminus B$ and $A - B$ used to denote set difference, but not $A / B$. Do you normally use that notation? =)

Comment: Is using a _forward_ slash for set difference standard notation?

Comment: bleech... I'm left/right backslash challenged...I got points taken off for doing that on a topology test once.

Comment: @David Mitra: The forward slashes were bothersome, so I was changing things to setminus, and in the middle they changed to backslash. Not thinking, I continued. Can turn them to backslash if you wish.

Comment: Thanks. \setminus is better of course. I'm not sure if \backslash is a mathop...

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating on the last post,

$\begin{array}{l}
A \cup B\\
 = (A \cup {A^c}) \cap (A \cup B)\\
 = A \cup ({A^c} \cap B)\\
 = (A \cap (B \cup {B^c})) \cup ({A^c} \cap B)\\
 = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap {B^c}) \cup ({A^c} \cap B)
\end{array}$

Note that these 3 sets are mutually disjoint, since

$\begin{array}{l}
(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap {B^c}) = A \cap (B \cap {B^c}) = A \cap \Phi  = \Phi \\
(A \cap B) \cap ({A^c} \cap B) = (A \cap {A^c}) \cap B = \Phi  \cap B = \Phi 
\end{array}$

Hence, by basic addition rule for counting,

$\begin{array}{l}
|A \cup B|\\
 = |A \cap B| + |A \cap {B^c}| + |{A^c} \cap B|\;\;\;\;\;\;\ldots (1)
\end{array}$

Again, we have

$\begin{array}{l}
A = A \cap (B \cup {B^c}) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap {B^c})\\
B = (A \cup {A^c}) \cap B = (A \cap B) \cup ({A^c} \cap B)
\end{array}$

Again, these 3 sets are mutually disjoint, as shown earlier.
Hence, by basic addition rule for counting,

$\begin{array}{l}
|A| = |A \cap B| + |A \cap {B^c}| \Rightarrow |A \cap {B^c}| = |A| - |A \cap B|\\
|B| = |A \cap B| + |{A^c} \cap B| \Rightarrow |{A^c} \cap B| = |B| - |A \cap B|
\end{array}$

Hence, from (1), we get

$\begin{array}{l}
|A \cup B|\\
 = |A \cap B| + |A \cap {B^c}| + |{A^c} \cap B|\\
 = |A \cap B| + |A| - |A \cap B| + |B| - |A \cap B|\\
 = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|
\end{array}$  (Proved)