# Why does $\#(X\cup Y)=\#(X)+\#(Y)-\#(X\cup Y)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across the following claim in a [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Union_and_intersection):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then, if $\# X$ denotes the cardinality of $X$, $$\#(X\cup Y)=\#(X)+\#(Y)-\#(X\cap Y),$$ so that if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, then
>   $$\#(X\cup Y)= \#(X)+\#(Y).$$

Upon searching several questions on this site, it appeared multiple times, but only once proved (for example, it was merely stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418569/let-x-and-y-be-finite-sets-then-x-cup-y-is-finite-and-x-cup-y-leq), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232052/proving-the-set-identity-x-cup-y-x-y-x-cap-y), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660379/cardinality-of-x-cup-y); it was proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82030/size-of-a-union-of-two-sets), but in a similar manner as $(\star)$. My goal is to construct a bijection $j:X\cup Y\to \Bbb N_{m+n-k}$, see below, and not to prove the claim in this way). Geometrically, if we were to consider a set diagram like the following: [image: set_diagram] The claim makes perfect sense, considering that 
$$\left. 
\begin{align}
\#(X \cup Y) &= \#((X \Delta Y) + \#(X \cap Y)) \\ 
&=\#(X \Delta Y)+\#(X \cap Y) \\
 &=\#(X)-\#(X \cap Y)+\#(Y)-\#(X \cap Y)+\#(X\cap Y) \\ 
&= \#(X)+\#(Y)-\#(X\cap Y)
\end{align} 
\right\}(\star)$$
but I have geometrically inferred these equalites; I have not rigorously proven them. Moreover, assuming that $f:X\to\Bbb N_n$ and $g:Y\to\Bbb N_m$ are bijective, so that $\#(X)=n$ and $\#(Y)=m$, if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, then the map $h:X\cup Y\to\Bbb N_{n+m}$, which we define as
$$h(a):=\begin{cases}f(a) &\text{if} \ a\in X \\ g(a)+n &\text{if} \ a\in\{x\}\end{cases},$$
is a bijection. Indeed, $h\vert_X=f$ was hypothesized as bijective. As for $h\vert_Y=g(a)+n$, a priori we have that $$\forall y\in\Bbb N_m\exists !x\in Y[y=g(x)],$$
and thus $$\forall y\in\Bbb N_{m+n}\exists ! x\in Y[y=f(x)].$$ My problem is the case that $X\cap Y\neq\emptyset$ — how can I construct a bijection $j:X\cup Y\to\Bbb N_{m+n-k}$, where $k=\#(X\cap Y)$?

Comment: You may deduce the case $X\cap Y\neq\emptyset$ given the case $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. Set $X'=X-X\cap Y$.

Comment: @Suzet Could you be a little more specific. You don't have to give me a full answer, just a more substantial hint.

Comment: Given the case you already treated, you know that $\#(X'\cup Y)=\#(X')+\#(Y)$. Now, you need to show that $X'\cup Y=X\cup Y$ (this should be ok by double inclusion), and that $\#(X')=\#(X)-\#(X\cup Y)$. That is, you need to show that if $A$ is a finite set, $B$ a subset of $A$, then $\#(A-B)=\#(A)-\#(B)$

Comment: @Suzet How could $\#(X')=\#(X)-\#(X\cup Y)$ if $\#(X\cup Y)\ge\#(X)$? Cardinality cannot be negative.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a typo. I meant $\#(X\cap Y)$ of course. $\#(X')=\#(X)-\#(X\cap Y)$

Comment: @Suzet So, if this is true, why should it hold that $\#(A\smallsetminus B)=\#(A)+\#(B)$ for *any* two sets $A$ and $B$?

Comment: The correct statement is: $\#(A\setminus B)=\#(A)-\#(B)$ whenever $B\subset A$. This is true because $\{B, A\setminus B\}$ forms a partition of $A$. Here is the proof of the general statement: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Principle_of_Counting

Comment: @Suzet Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a bijection you can construct it this way.

Start with a bijection from $X$ to $N_m$. Now you've mapped the $k$ elements of $X \cap Y$, so you need to deal with the other $n-k$ of those. Choose a bijection to $N_{n-k}$. Then add $m$ to all the values in the range and you have a bijection to $N_{m+n-k}$.

Now you have an answer. You should forget it. It's only good for finite sets although the the underlying fact is much more general. Not every proof of a theorem about cardinality should depend on an explicit bijection. Once you have tools proved that way, use them.

Answer (score 2):

You merely have to prove additivity; that the cardinality for a union of two disjoint finite sets is the sum of the cardinality for each set.

Let finite sets $A,B$ be disjoint.   Show $\#(A\cup B)=\#(A)+\#(B)$.

*Once you have accepted that*, it follows that *if* finite set $X\cup Y$ can be partitioned into a finite countable union of disjoint subsets, then you may sum their cardinalities.

Since $\{X,(Y\smallsetminus X)\}$ is a partition of $X\cup Y$, and $\{(Y\smallsetminus X),(X\cap Y)\}$ partitions $Y$, (do they?) then we are done:

$$\#(X\cup Y) ~{= \#(X\cup(Y\smallsetminus X)) \\= \#(X)+\#(Y\smallsetminus X)\\=\#(X)+\#(Y)-\#(X\cap Y)}$$

Answer (score 0):

At the moment that you sum the cardinal of the elements in $X$ with the cardinal of the elements in $Y$ you would be counting twice the common elements that is why you got to subtract once the elements you counted twice.

Comment: Yes, but what about a bijection?

Comment: you don't need that extra complication

Comment: I understand. But, that’s not what I asked in the question.

Comment: at the moment you biject both $X$  and  $Y$ onto respective subsets of $\Bbb N$, you need to keep track of the elements in $X\cap Y$, necessarily.

Comment: It is unnessecary, @janmarqz. You merely need to confirm that the finite sets $X\smallsetminus Y, X\cap Y, Y\smallsetminus X$ are pairwise disjoint and that their union is $X\cup Y$.  Then you may use the finite additivity property which you have demonstrated.

Comment: I coincide with you @GrahamKemp